# Conversion from string to int does not work

Tags: php, int, type-conversion

I use a regex to get a value from a document and store it in a variable called `$distance`. That is a string, but I have to put it in an int column of a table in a database.

Of course, normally I would go and say

```
$distance=intval($distance);
```

But it doesn't work! I really don't know why.

This is all I am doing:

```
preg_match_all($regex,$content,$match);
$distance=$match[0][1];
$distance=intval($distance);
```

The regex is correct, if I echo $distance, it is e.g. "0" - but I need it to be 0 instead of "0". Using intval() will somehow always convert it to an empty string.

### EDIT 1

The regex is this:

```
$regex='#<value>(.+?)</value>#'; // Please, I know I shouldn't use regex for parsing XML - but that is not the problem right now
```

Then I proceed with

```
preg_match_all($regex,$content,$match);
$distance=$match[0][1];
$distance=intval($distance);
```

Comment: Dump your distance variable before parsing it, it's hard to see what's wrong if you don't show the string you're dealing with... And the regex, too

Comment: I could be wrong, and/or missing something, but I think that the string value of "0" will make it into the int column in your database without any conversion.

Comment: Have you tried a simple conversion like `$distance = (int) $distance;`?

Comment: Yes, I have tried (int), too - see the regex above.

Comment: What does distance echo *before* you try to convert it? Try seeing its length? Perhaps there's white space?

Comment: Before that it is NULL. Dumping it gives me this: string(16) "0"

Comment: Then, shouldn't the question be "Conversion from NULL to int does not work"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd do `print_r($match)` you'd see that the array you need is `$match[1]`:

```
$content = '<value>1</value>, <value>12</value>';

$regex='#<value>(.+?)</value>#';

preg_match_all($regex,$content,$match);

print_r($match);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <value>1</value>
            [1] => <value>12</value>
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 12
        )

)
```

---

In this case:

```
$distance = (int) $match[1][1];

var_dump($distance);
```

Output: `int(12)`

---

Alternatively, you can use `PREG_SET_ORDER` flag, i.e. `preg_match_all($regex,$content,$match,$flags=PREG_SET_ORDER);`, $match array has this structure:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <value>1</value>
            [1] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => <value>12</value>
            [1] => 12
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

There must be a space, or possibly (been there, done that) an 0xA0 byte before the zero. Use "\d" in your regexp to be sure to get digits.

Edit: you can clean up the value with

```
$value = (int)trim($value, " \t\r\n\x0B\xA0\x00");
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Comment: How exactly? I am not sure how to integrate `\d` in the regex

Comment: You can use something like '#<value>\D*([\d]+?)\D*</value>#' (this would catch only integers and would fail against e.g. " 3.1415") -- or maybe better, you can trim() the value before running (int). If the problem is plain space or carriage return, trim() should do. Not sure about the cursed 0xA0 character ("nonbreaking space")

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need the question mark in your regex? Try this:

```
$regex='#<value>(.+)</value>#';
```